# If staments dentro de una funcion

Tags: python, funciones

Estoy haciendo una funcion para validar el numero menor de 6 parametros(de los cuales 1 es string), entonces quisiera saber como poner condicionales dentro de la sentencia de la funcion, ya que no me funciona.

Comment: Y por que no utilozas `*args`?

Comment: ¿Por qué eliminaste el código? Tu pregunta ahora luce muy amplia.

Answer (score 0):

Para calcular el mínimo de una lista puedes usar este código. :

```
codigo = "Ca1279 ";
lista = [];
lista.append( float(input("ingresa nota 1 ")));
lista.append( float(input("ingresa nota 2 ")));
lista.append( float(input("ingresa nota 3 ")));
lista.append( float(input("ingresa nota 4 ")));
lista.append( float(input("ingresa nota 5 ")));
#Aquí empieza el cálculo del mínimo
min = lista[0];
for nota in lista:
    if(nota < min):
        min = nota;
print (min);
```

Esto te dará el mínimo de la lista.

Answer (score 0):

SI utilizamos una `*args` todo se vuelve más fácil, esto se usa cuando se recibe una cantidad variable de argumentos, pero yo lo usaré por que son varios argumentos y la mayoría son del mismo tipo de dato. También se puede hacer de forma *normal* sin hacer muchos cambios.

```py
def nota_quices(*notas):
    if len(notas)!=6 or type(notas[0]) != str: 
        raise ValueError("Error de argumentos")
    #asignamos el nuevo valor a las variables
    codigo = notas[0]
    notas = notas[1:]

    if len(set(notas))==1: #si las notas son iguales
        return f"El promedio del estudiante {codigo} es {notas[1]}"

    notas = sorted(notas) 
    #sacamos el promedio
    prom = sum(notas[1:])/(len(notas)-1)
    return f"El promedio del estudiante {codigo} es {round(prom,2)}"
```

Con `len(set(notas))==1` se crea un set de datos (datos sin repeticiones) y si la longitud de esto es igual a 1 entonces significa que los notas se repiten por lo que solo retornamos el código y cualquier nota, dado que el promedio de `(x+x+x+x+x)/5` va a ser `x`. De lo contrario utilizamos la función `sorted` para ordenar de menor a mayor y omitimos el primer dato (la menor nota) y luego sacamos el promedio de esos datos, finalmente retornamos los datos.

La implementación a tu código sería así:

```py
def nota_quices(*notas):
    if len(notas)!=6 or type(notas[0]) != str: 
        raise ValueError("Error de argumentos")
    #asignamos el nuevo valor a las variables
    codigo = notas[0]
    notas = notas[1:]

    if len(set(notas))==1: #si las notas son iguales
        return f"El promedio del estudiante {codigo} es {notas[1]}"

    notas = sorted(notas) 
    #sacamos el promedio
    prom = sum(notas[1:])/(len(notas)-1)
    return f"El promedio del estudiante {codigo} es {round(prom,2)}" 

codigo = "Ca1279 "
n1 = float(input("ingresa nota 1 "))
n2 = float(input("ingresa nota 2 "))
n3 = float(input("ingresa nota 3 "))
n4 = float(input("ingresa nota 4 "))
n5 = float(input("ingresa nota 5 "))

print(nota_quices(codigo,n1,n2,n3,n4,n5))
```